# Define group $G^*$ with same elements as $G$ and prove mapping from $G$ to $G^*$ is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am asked to take a group $G$, define a new group $G^*$ that has the same elements of $G$ with operation $*$ defined as $a*b=ba$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $G^*$.  Then, prove that the mapping from $G$ to $G^*$ defined by $\phi(x) = x^{-1}$ for all $x$ in $G$ is an isomorphism from $G$ onto $G^*$.

So, here is what I have so far.  I know if I take the element $(ab)$ and perform the operation $\phi$, I get 
$$
\phi(ab)=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=\phi(b)\phi(a)=\phi(a)*\phi(b)$$
which I believe shows that $\phi(x)$ is abelian.  I'm kind of lost at this point of what I should do from here.

Comment: Good catch!  Can't believe I missed it.

Comment: Saying that $\phi(x)$ is abelian means nothing. A *group* can be abelian, not an element of a group. You are indeed finished, because $\phi$ is clearly bijective.

Comment: I have to ask (since I'm terrible at proofs), but is what I have written (minus the abelian part) enough to answer the question?

Comment: No, you have to justify that $\phi$ is bijective, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just note that $\phi(b)\phi(a)=\phi(a)\ast \phi(b)$. Then $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\ast \phi(b)$. Clearly the map $\phi$ is injective and surjective. So we obtain a group isomorphism $\phi\colon G\rightarrow G^*$.